# Restrict LOV based on multiple LOV's

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

- I have a city column with cities: (New York, Miami).
- And an area column with areas: (North, South, West, east).
- And shops column: (Shop a, shop b, shop c)

Suppose that I have the following records

```
1- (New York, North, Shop a) 
2- (Miami, North, shop c)
3-  (New York, south, Shop b)
```

I need to create three LOV’s, the first one is city, the second one is area and the last is shop. If I select New York in the city LOV from the database, I need the area options in the area LOV to be north and south and, if I select North I want only shop a to appear in the shop LOV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you have those "following records"? In a table? I presume.

Basically, you have to create a cascading list of lists of values.

The first LoV (for e.g. `P1_CITY` item) would contain cities:

```
select distinct city d, city r
from your_table
order by city
```

The second (for `P1_AREA` item) would then select areas that belong to selected city:

```
select distinct area d, area r
from your_table
where city = :P1_CITY
order by area
```

Do not forget to set Cascading LoV property for the 2nd LoV! Should be `P1_CITY` item.

The same goes for shops:

```
select distinct shop d, shop r
from your_table
where city = :P1_CITY
  and area = :P1_AREA
order by shop
```

by setting Cascading LoV to both `P1_CITY, P1_AREA`.

Comment: Yes in a table. 

What if area is null (I did not select an area and I selected a city), is the shop LOV going to show me all the shops that related to the chosen city?

Comment: No, it would return *nothing*. You should modify WHERE clause to `... and (area = :P1_AREA or :P1_AREA is null)`

Comment: Good. If I have one more LoV, lets say neighbourhood, the query would be like this: . . . and (area =:p1_area or :p1_area is null) and (neighbourhood =:p1_ neighbourhood or :p1_ neighbourhood is null) right?

Comment: Exactly like that, yes.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot :)